# Arraylist - how to load elements X times?

Tags: java, arrays, int

I am a newbie and working on this code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Text 1");
    list.add("Text 2");
    list.add("Text 3");

    System.out.println("#1 normal for loop");
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
```

I want to load the content of the list, X times. X is defined in a int variable.

So, if `int myuserinput = 2`, the output should be:

```
Text1
Text2
Text3

Text1
Text2
Text3
```

I have tryed to change `list.size()` and `i++` to `myuserinput`(because it sounds logical), but no luck.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: *"Any suggestions?"*  Don't forget to add a '?' to questions!

Comment: what about using `for` loop?

Comment: *"but no luck."*  1) Try describing a) What you expected to happen b) What actually happened, and for utility c) Why you expected (a) to happen. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enclose your for loop inside other loop, which will run for user specified number of times and print the elements from the list.

```
int myuserinput = 2; // Can read this from user

for(int k=0;k<myuserinput;k++){
  // Process the list specified number of times
  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
     System.out.println(list.get(i));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Put another loop around your loop, like this:

```
int numTimes = 2;
for (int j = 0; j < numTimes; j++) {
    System.out.println("#1 normal for loop");
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Prints that it's the #1 time for every time, probably not wanted behavior.

Comment: Yes, I left that part to the OP. I did like the way you handled it though.

Answer (score 1):

A nested for-loop is what you are searching for

```
for(int counter = 0; counter < x; counter++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
}
```

Then every time it loops through the first for-loop it loops through the entire ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

To run a loop multiple times, simply put the loop inside another loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_TIMES_TO_RUN; i++){
    System.out.println("#" + time + " normal for loop");
    for (String s : list) { //Alternate idiom for iterating thru a list
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int myuserinput = 2;
for(int i = 0;i<myuserinput;i++){
    for(String s:list) {
      System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`for int i = 0; i < myuserinput; i++`

you must do! The all works

Comment: Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Answer (score 0):

Add a loop, like this

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < X; i++) { // Add all three items X times.
  list.add("Text 1");
  list.add("Text 2");
  list.add("Text 3");
}

System.out.println("#2 normal for loop");
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```